# How can I make my Inline Buttons responsive?

Tags: html, css

I am having a bit Problem with my 3 buttons that I am using for my site. I somehow managed to show all my three buttons in a single line (As you can see in the snippet) but I am not able to make them responsive. Means, when the screen size reduces (i.e. to 380dpi), I want my 1 out 3 buttons to shift to the bottom and the rest 2 buttons to remain on top but in center. As you can see in the attached picture. 
 [image: As shown in this Pic.] 
I am not good in coding, that's why I request you, people, to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set 'flex-wrap: wrap' to the element with a class testing.